# Check if view equals to another

Tags: android, android-view

I have a view which I get from the parent ViewGroup:

```
mActiveCard = getChildAt(LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK);
```

I later what to check if mActiveCard equals to another view:

```
anotherCard = getChildAt(x);
```

A naive approach would have been to check if x== LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK however there might be many changes in the ViewGroup e.g. removed objects. So the positions are relative.
Also I can save the object for later but that will consume some more memory, like:

```
mActiveCard.equals( getChildAt(LAST_OBJECT_IN_STACK) )
```

One idea is to setId() of the view or setTag(). So if I have a unique String/int then I could later get the id or the tag. So saving just the id/tag would require less memory, right?

First of all is my theory correct? Also, does Android SDK offer a way to identify tags and what can be an good id/tag to generate and set on that view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly holding onto a reference to a View (mActiveCard) that you know is also in the child list, you can simply compare their references.

```
if (mActiveCard == getChildAt(x))
{
    // ...
}
```